# RxJava kotlin flatmap chain network coroutine returning Result

Tags: android, kotlin, rx-java, kotlin-coroutines

Just to begin with I have never used RxJava before. I have to implement an SDK which is using AndroidRx or RxJava for all use cases and examples provided.

I have the following method returning data from backend

```
override suspend fun getSomeData(token: String): Outcome<String, DataError> {
        val getSomeDataMutation = GetSomeDataMutation(token)

        try {
            val response = apolloClient.mutate(getSomeDataMutation).await()

            return if (response.data?.someData != null) {
                Outcome.success(response.data!!.someData)
            } else {
                Outcome.error(DataError.AN_ERROR(R.string.error))
            }
        } catch(...)
```

Now I'm trying to implement the method shown below to interact with that SDK using RxJava which will call the above method in flatmap(based on example).
Is that even possible ?
I have been trying for a few hours and without any success. If I modify the above method to return SingleSource it would work but I can't do that.

```
TheSDK.requestToken()
            .rx()
            .flatMap { token ->
                network.getSomeData(token)  //this part is causing the problem
            }
            .flatMap { networkResult->
                return@flatMap TheSDK.session(SomeResponse.with(apiResult)).rx()
            }
            .subscribe { sessResult, throwable ->
                if (sessResult!= null) {
                    if (sessResult.isSuccessful) {
                        // success
                    } else {
                        // something wrong
                    }
                } else {
                    //an error occurred during the stream
                }
            }
```

Comment: Basically the same answer as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65616836/how-to-call-a-coroutine-usecase-from-a-rxjava-flat-map/65634846#65634846

Answer (score 0):

I think that you are using the wrong method.

You should use `.flatMap` when you are trying to chain 2 reactive things

```
 fun myFun(): Single<String> {
    val intSingle: Single<Int> = Single.just(1)
    val stringSingle: Single<String> = Single.just("foo")

    return intSingle
        .flatMap { stringSingle }
}
```

On the other hand, you should use `.map` whe you are trying to chain a reactive thing with a non-reactive one

```
 fun myFun(): Single<String> {
    val intSingle: Single<Int> = Single.just(1)
    val string: String = "foo"

    return intSingle
        .map { string }
}
```

Looking at your code I believe the solution would be:

```
TheSDK.requestToken()
        .rx()
        .map{ token ->
            network.getSomeData(token)  // returns something non-reactive
        }
        .flatMap { networkResult->
            TheSDK.session(SomeResponse.with(apiResult))
                .rx()
        }
        .subscribe(
            { result ->
                // do something onSuccess
            },
            { error ->
                // do something onError
            }
        )
```

As you can see I also used a subscriber where you can pass 2 lambdas, an `onSuccess` and `onError`